# How can a three month old go to sleep - everything's so interesting!

Tags: infant, sleep

Our three month old daughter has recently started to have trouble falling asleep. Not even falling - she has trouble starting to fall asleep!

I have learned and accepted her way of falling asleep. Rocked on my arms she would fuss/cry for several minutes, pass some gas during that, and then just close her eyes and peacefully go to sleep.

However, since a few days ago when she had yet another level-up, she started to find everything so interesting that she doesn't even start falling asleep. She curiously looks around, smiles broadly, grabs blanket or my sleeping robe, generally has fun. We do not share her positive attitute towards evening fun.

The same applies to falling asleep for the third time at night (around 4AM, she seems to want to stop sleeping at all then) and for her naps. It's very difficult to put her to her afternoon nap.

Once she enters her (previously mentioned) falling asleep state, she does go to sleep as usual, or even better. But reaching that point is the problem.

What can we do?

Answer (score 3):

> We do not share her positive attitute towards evening fun.

Why not? She's not upset, she's not making a ruckus, she's just busy discovering the world. If she doesn't cry, but just happily explores her surroundings, just let her do that.

Kids will sleep when they need to. Try adjusting the schedule, perhaps eliminating a daytime nap. Sleep schedules are based on the average baby. Yours may not be average in this regard.

Comment: Our baby is and always has been below average. We have our pre-sleep feeding at a specified time and we stick to it. By that time she is usually very fussy (she has trouble with her afternoon nap) and very tired and sleepy. Feeding seems to regenerate her somehow.

Comment: I know it may not be your intention, but phrases like "We dont share her positive attitude" and "Our baby is and always has been below average" do not sound very supportive, even if out of context. I don't want to be one of those people on the internet, but your choice of words makes me cringe.

Answer (score 1):

Have a dark calm sleeping area? If she's happy lying there looking around but not sleeping I don't think it's a problem.  You might find that she adjusts and learns to settle.

Is she crying after a time when you put her down?

Comment: Sometimes, but we usually only put her down once she's asleep or reeeeally dozy. The sleeping area's very dim, but there's a closet and a lamp, and that's enough.